# Missing properties in python's datetime module

Tags: python, datetime, properties, module

I came across datetime module in python, as this is first time i need it in my scripts.

But I really have a problem with it, in example:

```
import datetime

date_now = datetime.date.today()

print date_now
```

As an answer i get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "datetime.py", line 3, in
>
> ```
> import datetime
> ```
>
> File "/root/Desktop/python_work/datetime.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> today = datetime.date.today()
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'date'

Then i checked my datetime module to list properties:

import datetime

```
for p in dir(datetime):

    print p
```

As a result i got only:

```
> __builtins__
> 
> __doc__
> 
> __file__
> 
> __name__
> 
> __package__
> 
> datetime
```

And yeah, true, 'module' object has no attribute 'date', it really do not have it.

Is there any idea, what should be added to python install or how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a file of your own named `datetime.py` that's in your module path. You can see that from the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "datetime.py", line 3, in
import datetime
File "/root/Desktop/python_work/datetime.py", line 5, in
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Instead of importing the `datetime.py` in your site-packages, you're importing the `datetime.py` in `/root/Desktop/python_work`.

In fact, it seems probable that `datetime.py` is the actual script you're running, in which case you're just importing yourself.

The solution is to rename the script. And, in general, do not give scripts the same name as modules in the stdlib—especially modules you plan to use.

Answer (score 6):

Rename your file from `datetime.py"` to something else. This name is conflicting with the builtin `datetime` module. Hence the error.

Comment: yes, i havent even noted the name of file, i just put that as testing script, as always i make testscript for each part of main. Accidentally called it with the same name... Thanks for notation!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU

IT

SOLVED

MY PROBLEM. I HAD A FILE NAMED datetime.py I changed it to dt((DATETIME)).py

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31112414)